# What causes: Unix transport error?

Tags: nhibernate, postgresql, nunit

I'm doing unit test(using NUnit) on Postgresql, unfortunately it causes an error:

```
Internal error
    RemotingException: Unix transport error.
```

Note: The error doesn't happen if I'm using Sqlite

Code:

```
 using System;
 using ncfg = NHibernate.Cfg;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Reflection;
 using NHibernate;
 using System.Data;
 using NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl;
 using NHibernate.Dialect;
 using NHibernate.Driver;
 using NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu;
 using NUnit.Framework;
 using NHibernate.Mapping;



 namespace RuntimeNhibernate
 {
  class MainClass
  {
   public static void Main (string[] args)
   {


    using(var c = new BlogTestFixture())
    {
     c.CanSaveAndLoadBlog();

    }

   }
  }



  public class InMemoryDatabaseTest : IDisposable
  {
   private static ncfg.Configuration Configuration;
   private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory;
   protected ISession session;

   public InMemoryDatabaseTest(Assembly assemblyContainingMapping)
   {
    if (Configuration == null)
    {

     Configuration = new ncfg.Configuration()
      .SetProperty(ncfg.Environment.ReleaseConnections,"on_close")
      .SetProperty(ncfg.Environment.Dialect, typeof (SQLiteDialect).AssemblyQualifiedName)
      .SetProperty(ncfg.Environment.ConnectionDriver, typeof(SQLite20Driver).AssemblyQualifiedName)
      .SetProperty(ncfg.Environment.ConnectionString, "data source=:memory:")
      .SetProperty(ncfg.Environment.ProxyFactoryFactoryClass, typeof (ProxyFactoryFactory).AssemblyQualifiedName)
      .AddAssembly(assemblyContainingMapping);


     /*Configuration = new ncfg.Configuration()
      .SetProperty(ncfg.Environment.ReleaseConnections,"on_close")
      .SetProperty(ncfg.Environment.Dialect, typeof (PostgreSQLDialect).AssemblyQualifiedName)
      .SetProperty(ncfg.Environment.ConnectionDriver, typeof(NpgsqlDriver).AssemblyQualifiedName)
      .SetProperty(ncfg.Environment.ConnectionString, "Server=127.0.0.1;Database=memdb;User ID=postgres;Password=password;Pooling=false;")
      .SetProperty(ncfg.Environment.ProxyFactoryFactoryClass, typeof (ProxyFactoryFactory).AssemblyQualifiedName)
      .AddAssembly(assemblyContainingMapping);*/

     SessionFactory = Configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();

    new SchemaExport(Configuration).Execute(true, true, false, session.Connection, Console.Out);
   }

   public void Dispose()
   {
    session.Dispose();
   }
  }//class InMemory

  public class Blog
  {
   public virtual int BlogId { get; set; }
   public virtual bool AllowsComments { set; get; }
   public virtual DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
   public virtual string Subtitle { get; set; }
   public virtual string Title { get; set; }
  }

  [TestFixture]
  public class BlogTestFixture : InMemoryDatabaseTest
  {
   public BlogTestFixture() : base(typeof(Blog).Assembly)
   {
   }


   [Test]
   public void IsOK()
   {
    Assert.AreEqual(true, true);
    return;
   }

   [Test]     
   public void CanSaveAndLoadBlog()
   {


    object id;




    using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
     id = session.Save(new Blog
     {
      AllowsComments = true,
      CreatedAt = new DateTime(2000,1,1),
      Subtitle = "Hello",
      Title = "World",
     });

     tx.Commit();
    }

    session.Clear();

    Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}", id);


    using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
     var blog = session.Get<Blog>(id);




     Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1), blog.CreatedAt);
     Assert.AreEqual("Hello", blog.Subtitle);
     Assert.AreEqual("World", blog.Title);
     Assert.AreEqual(true, blog.AllowsComments);

     tx.Commit();
    }
   }
  }//Test


 }//namespace
```

What could be the possible reason when I unit test Postgresql, it results to  **RemotingException: Unix transport error.** ?

If I run the code outside of unit test (e.g. Main), it works. Btw, if I unit test Sqlite, it doesn't cause any errors too

Comment: Sounds like your program is trying to connect through a socket rather than a port. Can you configure the connector to use the Postgres  TCP/IP port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, I tried launching MonoDevelop from **Terminal** (/Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/monodevelop), I saw the more detailed error from the commandline when I ran the unit tests.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' from assembly 'Npgsql'.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.MonoCustomAttrs:GetCustomAttributesInternal (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider,System.Type,bool)
  at System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetCustomAttributesBase (ICustomAttributeProvider obj, System.Type attributeType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetCustomAttributes (ICustomAttributeProvider obj, System.Type attributeType, Boolean inherit) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCustomAttributes (System.Type attributeType, Boolean inherit) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetNeutralResourcesLanguage (System.Reflection.Assembly a) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Resources.ResourceManager..ctor (System.Type resourceSource) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod*,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Then I tried changing the Npgsql version(the one that causes an error came from http://pgfoundry.org/frs/download.php/2868/Npgsql2.0.11-bin-ms.net4.0.zip) to http://pgfoundry.org/frs/download.php/2860/Npgsql2.0.11-bin-mono2.0.zip After this, there's no more **Unix transport error** ^_^

Lesson learned, use the Mono version of the component you are using if you are running things on Mono

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurs, when a unit test in MonoDevelop raises an exception, which could not be caught by the test runner (i.e. when the test starts some threads and they crash).

If you have such a test which is grey even after running

[image: not executable test]

and the unit test pad shows the internal error

[image]

you should try running the test on your console with `nunit-console` (should be in the repo of your distro where `mono` comes from) and leak the exception.

In my case it was a simple multiple enumeration exception in a sub-thread of my test.

```
Unhandled exceptions:
1) Residata.Platform.Server.Message.Test.MemoryBrokerTest.AssertThatReceiveMethodWaitsUntilPublish : System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[Residata.Platform.Contract.Message.IPackage].MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```